# Overloaded method selection logic

Tags: c#, overloading

Given the following overloaded methods:

```
public string Test(long item)
{
    return "Test with a long was called!";
}

public string Test(int item)
{
    return "Test with an int was called!";
}

public string Test(object item)
{
    return "Test with an object was called!";
}
```

When I call `Test()`, passing a `short`, like this:

```
short shortValue = 7;
var result = Test(shortValue);
```

Why is the value `result` equal to `"Test with an int was called!"`, instead of `"Test with an object was called!"`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is the value result equal to "Test with an int was called!", instead of "Test with an object was called!"?

The conversion to `int` is "better" than the conversion to `object`, so the overload taking `int` is "better" than the one taking `object` - and both are applicable as `short` is implicitly convertible to both `int` and `object`. (The overload taking `long` is also applicable, but the conversion to `int` is better than the one to `long`, too.)

See section 7.5.3 of the C# language specification for general overloading rules, and 7.5.3.3 for the rules about "better conversions". There's little point in writing them all out here, as they're very long - but the most important aspect is that there's a conversion from `int` to `object` but no conversion from `object` to `int` - so the conversion to `int` is more specific, and therefore better.

(Section numbers are from the C# 4 and C# 5 versions. You can download the [C# 5 spec](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) in Word format.)

Comment: +1 - Ah, thought it would prefer inheritance over conversion. Good to know, thanks for the link to the C# spec.

Answer (score 2):

The C# specification rules mean that the compiler prefers converting a `short` to `int`, not to `object`. I think this is due to the following rule from [7.5.3.5 Better conversion target](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552) (link is to C# 5 spec download, or see [equivalent from C# 1.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691339%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) online)

> Given two different types T1 and T2, T1 is a better conversion target than T2 if at least one of the following holds:
>
> - An implicit conversion from T1 to T2 exists, and no implicit conversion from T2 to T1 exists
> - T1 is a signed integral type and T2 is an unsigned integral type. [other content omitted]

To rewrite it for this scenario, since an implicit conversion from `int` to `object` exists, and no implicit conversion from `object` to `int` exists, converting to `int` is the better conversion.